# Watson speech-to-text numericals

Tags: ibm-watson

Working with Speech to Text service and noticed that it doesn't recognize numbers when you say them. For example if I say three hundred and forty three it won't write '343' and writes 'three hundred and forty three' instead. Siri on the other hand can convert to three hundred and forty three to 343 any way I can get around this, using Watson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working on this feature, but we don't have a release date yet. I will update this answer once we have it.